# sql query to show products_description?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with a Table called products_description, it has a column called products_name, inside products_name are 12000 entries but there are only about 200 different entry names, the question is how can I show only the 200 entries without showing copies of the same entry? eg fred which may be shown 30 times. I want to end up with a list of names from products_name column without copies. eg fred, tom, jack, thanks

Comment: could u post the table structure ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [MySQL SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> > > **DISTINCT** specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

So, the query that would do the trick should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `products_name`
FROM `products_description`
```

Comment: A link to the documentation for and a brief explanation of the `DISTINCT` keyword and its functionality would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  `products_name`
FROM `products_description` 
GROUP BY `products_name`
```

Comment: This would also do the trick, but keep in mind that **GROUP BY** has the downside that it needs extra time for ordering the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct

```
select distinct products_name from products_description;
```

Comment: perfect. but some of the entries in product_names have commas, like fred, ronny, tom,  so is it possible to only show the names without copies and without the commas? so if there are 200 different names I only want those, at the moment I am getting many copies because the names are someetimes in different orders like ronny, fred, tom, thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Basic: Use SELECT DISTINCT to discard duplicate rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT products_name FROM products_description
```

By using SELECT DISTINCT, only one instance of each products_name entity will appear, no duplicates, no repeatations.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT products_name
 FROM products_description;`

By using this query you can only see unique names. It avoids duplicate records.